# Gedit plugins error

Tags: python, gedit, plugins

i can 't run some plugin in gedit. when i run some plugin like " externaltools " program is closed and show this error in the terminal:

```
> > (gedit:11796): GVFS-RemoteVolumeMonitor-WARNING **: invoking IsSupported() failed for remote volume monitor with dbus name
> org.gtk.Private.GduVolumeMonitor:
> org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildSignaled: Process
> /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-gdu-volume-monitor received signal 6 Traceback
> (most recent call last):   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site.py",
> line 548, in <module>
>     main()   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 530, in main
>     known_paths = addusersitepackages(known_paths)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 266, in addusersitepackages
>     user_site = getusersitepackages()   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 241, in getusersitepackages
>     user_base = getuserbase() # this will also set USER_BASE   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 231, in getuserbase
>     USER_BASE = get_config_var('userbase')   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 516, in get_config_var
>     return get_config_vars().get(name)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 449, in get_config_vars
>     import re   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 105, in <module>
>     import sre_compile   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/sre_compile.py", line 14, in <module>
>     import sre_parse   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/sre_parse.py", line 17, in <module>
>     from sre_constants import *   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/sre_constants.py", line 18, in <module>
>     from _sre import MAXREPEAT ImportError: cannot import name MAXREPEAT
```

and question 2: what is the best gedit plugins for programing ?

sorry all for my english :-)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Under 'Help -> About' as you can see in the screen shot you'll find the build number of your currently used version of gedit, which you can match up with available [Gedit Plugins](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gedit#Plugins) on their HP.

I suggest you delete the broken plugins(s) and re-install it/them, matching your build.
For **External Tools** plugin there is an extensive [documentation](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gedit/Plugins/ExternalTools) on their HP, which might contain some useful information to you!

- It may be worth a shot to simply reconfigure the plugin in your case:

**Using External Tools:**

1. To install the plugin, go to Edit -> Preferences -> Plugins -> External Tools.
2. To configure the plugin, go to Tools -> Manage External Tools.... A dialog will appear and you can start adding tools.
3. To run tools, go to Tools -> External Tools or use (if applicable) associated shortcut keys.

As for your second question, please refer to the plugin-link above, also [here](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gedit/FAQ#gedit_supports_Python_plugins.2C_but_I_prefer_to_write_in_Ruby.2BAC8-JS.2BAC8-Scheme.2BAC8-Perl.2BAC8-C.23.2BAC8-modula-2.2BAC8-whatever...) and [here](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/desktop-devel-list/2010-August/msg00036.html).